# Odata service call error : object is not an instance of declaring class

Tags: java, xml, jpa, odata

I am trying to create a Odata service in `Eclipse LUNA`.
I have followed wizard based approach.
There are two tables that I have used.

1. ZAE_GOODSRECPT
2. ZAE_PRODORDER

I created `JPA` entities from table in eclipse and as a result below classes are created from wizard.

**ZAEProdorder.java**

```
package model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Set;


/**
 * The persistent class for the ZAE_PRODORDER database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="ZAE_PRODORDER")
@NamedQuery(name="ZaeProdorder.findAll", query="SELECT z FROM ZaeProdorder z")
public class ZaeProdorder implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private ZaeProdorderPK id;

    @Column(length=50)
    private String barcode;

    @Column(length=10)
    private String batch;

    @Column(length=40)
    private String bfdat;

    @Column(length=12)
    private String cardate;

    @Column(length=4)
    private String ccook;

    @Column(length=60)
    private String compad;

    @Column(length=18)
    private String ean11;

    @Column(length=10)
    private String eddat;



    @Column(length=60)
    private String fifth;

    @Column(length=60)
    private String firstl;

    @Column(length=20)
    private String fld1;

    @Column(length=40)
    private String fld10;

    @Column(length=60)
    private String fld11;

    @Column(length=60)
    private String fld12;

    @Column(length=60)
    private String fld13;



    @Column(length=20)
    private String fld2;

    @Column(length=20)
    private String fld3;

    @Column(length=20)
    private String fld4;

    @Column(length=20)
    private String fld5;

    @Column(length=20)
    private String fld6;

    @Column(length=20)
    private String fld7;

    @Column(length=20)
    private String fld8;

    @Column(length=30)
    private String fld9;

    @Column(length=60)
    private String fourth;

    @Column(length=12)
    private String hsdate;

    @Column(length=4)
    private String jldat;

    @Column(length=5)
    private String jobno;

    @Column(length=6)
    private String lblno;

    @Column(length=9)
    private String line;

    @Column(length=10)
    private String lotno;

    @Column(length=40)
    private String maktx;

    @Column(length=5)
    private String manuf;

    @Column(length=5)
    private String matnr;



    @Column(length=1)
    private String ptype;

    @Column(length=60)
    private String qlify;

    @Column(length=45)
    private String rfgnf;

    @Column(length=60)
    private String secondl;



    @Column(length=12)
    private String serno;

    @Column(length=1)
    private String shift;

    @Column(length=60)
    private String sixth;

    @Column(length=10)
    private String slabd;

    @Column(length=10)
    private String tarag;

    @Column(length=4)
    private String teco;

    @Column(length=60)
    private String third;

    @Column(length=40)
    private String tihigh;

    @Column(length=60)
    private String title;

    @Column(precision=63)
    private double tolerance;

    @Column(length=20)
    private String weight;

    @Column(length=5)
    private String weight1;

    @Column(length=8)
    private String wgtkg;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to ZaeGoodsrecpt
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="zaeProdorder")
    private Set<ZaeGoodsrecpt> zaeGoodsrecpts;

    public ZaeProdorder() {
    }

    public ZaeProdorderPK getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(ZaeProdorderPK id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getBarcode() {
        return this.barcode;
    }

    public void setBarcode(String barcode) {
        this.barcode = barcode;
    }

    public String getBatch() {
        return this.batch;
    }

    public void setBatch(String batch) {
        this.batch = batch;
    }

    public String getBfdat() {
        return this.bfdat;
    }

    public void setBfdat(String bfdat) {
        this.bfdat = bfdat;
    }

    public String getCardate() {
        return this.cardate;
    }

    public void setCardate(String cardate) {
        this.cardate = cardate;
    }

    public String getCcook() {
        return this.ccook;
    }

    public void setCcook(String ccook) {
        this.ccook = ccook;
    }

    public String getCompad() {
        return this.compad;
    }

    public void setCompad(String compad) {
        this.compad = compad;
    }

    public String getEan11() {
        return this.ean11;
    }

    public void setEan11(String ean11) {
        this.ean11 = ean11;
    }

    public String getEddat() {
        return this.eddat;
    }

    public void setEddat(String eddat) {
        this.eddat = eddat;
    }



    public String getFifth() {
        return this.fifth;
    }

    public void setFifth(String fifth) {
        this.fifth = fifth;
    }

    public String getFirstl() {
        return this.firstl;
    }

    public void setFirstl(String firstl) {
        this.firstl = firstl;
    }

    public String getFld1() {
        return this.fld1;
    }

    public void setFld1(String fld1) {
        this.fld1 = fld1;
    }

    public String getFld10() {
        return this.fld10;
    }

    public void setFld10(String fld10) {
        this.fld10 = fld10;
    }

    public String getFld11() {
        return this.fld11;
    }

    public void setFld11(String fld11) {
        this.fld11 = fld11;
    }

    public String getFld12() {
        return this.fld12;
    }

    public void setFld12(String fld12) {
        this.fld12 = fld12;
    }

    public String getFld13() {
        return this.fld13;
    }

    public void setFld13(String fld13) {
        this.fld13 = fld13;
    }


    public String getFld2() {
        return this.fld2;
    }

    public void setFld2(String fld2) {
        this.fld2 = fld2;
    }

    public String getFld3() {
        return this.fld3;
    }

    public void setFld3(String fld3) {
        this.fld3 = fld3;
    }

    public String getFld4() {
        return this.fld4;
    }

    public void setFld4(String fld4) {
        this.fld4 = fld4;
    }

    public String getFld5() {
        return this.fld5;
    }

    public void setFld5(String fld5) {
        this.fld5 = fld5;
    }

    public String getFld6() {
        return this.fld6;
    }

    public void setFld6(String fld6) {
        this.fld6 = fld6;
    }

    public String getFld7() {
        return this.fld7;
    }

    public void setFld7(String fld7) {
        this.fld7 = fld7;
    }

    public String getFld8() {
        return this.fld8;
    }

    public void setFld8(String fld8) {
        this.fld8 = fld8;
    }

    public String getFld9() {
        return this.fld9;
    }

    public void setFld9(String fld9) {
        this.fld9 = fld9;
    }

    public String getFourth() {
        return this.fourth;
    }

    public void setFourth(String fourth) {
        this.fourth = fourth;
    }

    public String getHsdate() {
        return this.hsdate;
    }

    public void setHsdate(String hsdate) {
        this.hsdate = hsdate;
    }

    public String getJldat() {
        return this.jldat;
    }

    public void setJldat(String jldat) {
        this.jldat = jldat;
    }

    public String getJobno() {
        return this.jobno;
    }

    public void setJobno(String jobno) {
        this.jobno = jobno;
    }

    public String getLblno() {
        return this.lblno;
    }

    public void setLblno(String lblno) {
        this.lblno = lblno;
    }

    public String getLine() {
        return this.line;
    }

    public void setLine(String line) {
        this.line = line;
    }

    public String getLotno() {
        return this.lotno;
    }

    public void setLotno(String lotno) {
        this.lotno = lotno;
    }

    public String getMaktx() {
        return this.maktx;
    }

    public void setMaktx(String maktx) {
        this.maktx = maktx;
    }

    public String getManuf() {
        return this.manuf;
    }

    public void setManuf(String manuf) {
        this.manuf = manuf;
    }

    public String getMatnr() {
        return this.matnr;
    }

    public void setMatnr(String matnr) {
        this.matnr = matnr;
    }



    public String getPtype() {
        return this.ptype;
    }

    public void setPtype(String ptype) {
        this.ptype = ptype;
    }

    public String getQlify() {
        return this.qlify;
    }

    public void setQlify(String qlify) {
        this.qlify = qlify;
    }

    public String getRfgnf() {
        return this.rfgnf;
    }

    public void setRfgnf(String rfgnf) {
        this.rfgnf = rfgnf;
    }

    public String getSecondl() {
        return this.secondl;
    }

    public void setSecondl(String secondl) {
        this.secondl = secondl;
    }



    public String getSerno() {
        return this.serno;
    }

    public void setSerno(String serno) {
        this.serno = serno;
    }

    public String getShift() {
        return this.shift;
    }

    public void setShift(String shift) {
        this.shift = shift;
    }

    public String getSixth() {
        return this.sixth;
    }

    public void setSixth(String sixth) {
        this.sixth = sixth;
    }

    public String getSlabd() {
        return this.slabd;
    }

    public void setSlabd(String slabd) {
        this.slabd = slabd;
    }

    public String getTarag() {
        return this.tarag;
    }

    public void setTarag(String tarag) {
        this.tarag = tarag;
    }

    public String getTeco() {
        return this.teco;
    }

    public void setTeco(String teco) {
        this.teco = teco;
    }

    public String getThird() {
        return this.third;
    }

    public void setThird(String third) {
        this.third = third;
    }

    public String getTihigh() {
        return this.tihigh;
    }

    public void setTihigh(String tihigh) {
        this.tihigh = tihigh;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public double getTolerance() {
        return this.tolerance;
    }

    public void setTolerance(double tolerance) {
        this.tolerance = tolerance;
    }

    public String getWeight() {
        return this.weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(String weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public String getWeight1() {
        return this.weight1;
    }

    public void setWeight1(String weight1) {
        this.weight1 = weight1;
    }

    public String getWgtkg() {
        return this.wgtkg;
    }

    public void setWgtkg(String wgtkg) {
        this.wgtkg = wgtkg;
    }

    public Set<ZaeGoodsrecpt> getZaeGoodsrecpts() {
        return this.zaeGoodsrecpts;
    }

    public void setZaeGoodsrecpts(Set<ZaeGoodsrecpt> zaeGoodsrecpts) {
        this.zaeGoodsrecpts = zaeGoodsrecpts;
    }

    public ZaeGoodsrecpt addZaeGoodsrecpt(ZaeGoodsrecpt zaeGoodsrecpt) {
        getZaeGoodsrecpts().add(zaeGoodsrecpt);
        zaeGoodsrecpt.setZaeProdorder(this);

        return zaeGoodsrecpt;
    }

    public ZaeGoodsrecpt removeZaeGoodsrecpt(ZaeGoodsrecpt zaeGoodsrecpt) {
        getZaeGoodsrecpts().remove(zaeGoodsrecpt);
        zaeGoodsrecpt.setZaeProdorder(null);

        return zaeGoodsrecpt;
    }

}
```

**ZAEgoodsrecpt.java**

```
package model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;
import java.sql.Timestamp;


/**
 * The persistent class for the ZAE_GOODSRECPT database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="ZAE_GOODSRECPT")
@NamedQuery(name="ZaeGoodsrecpt.findAll", query="SELECT z FROM ZaeGoodsrecpt z")
public class ZaeGoodsrecpt implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private ZaeGoodsrecptPK id;

    @Column(length=70)
    private String barcode;

    @Column(length=40)
    private String bfdat;

    @Column(length=20)
    private String charg;

    @Column(length=10)
    private String cookcode;

    @Column(length=3)
    private String cwmvemeh;

    @Column(length=25)
    private String cwmvemng;

    @Column(length=10)
    private String hsdat;

    @Column(length=1)
    private String indc;

    @Column(length=5)
    private String manuf;

    @Column(length=18)
    private String matnr;

    @Column(length=10)
    private String mblnr;

    @Column(length=4)
    private String mjahr;

    @Column(length=20)
    private String printdate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date proddate;



    @Column(precision=10)
    private BigDecimal seq;

    @Column(nullable=false, length=1)
    private String status;

    @Column(length=3)
    private String vemeh;

    @Column(length=17)
    private String vemng;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to ZaeProdorder
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="AUFNR", referencedColumnName="AUFNR", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false),
    @JoinColumn(name="werks", referencedColumnName="werks", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)

    })
    private ZaeProdorder zaeProdorder;

    public ZaeGoodsrecpt() {
    }

    public ZaeGoodsrecptPK getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(ZaeGoodsrecptPK id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getBarcode() {
        return this.barcode;
    }

    public void setBarcode(String barcode) {
        this.barcode = barcode;
    }

    public String getBfdat() {
        return this.bfdat;
    }

    public void setBfdat(String bfdat) {
        this.bfdat = bfdat;
    }

    public String getCharg() {
        return this.charg;
    }

    public void setCharg(String charg) {
        this.charg = charg;
    }

    public String getCookcode() {
        return this.cookcode;
    }

    public void setCookcode(String cookcode) {
        this.cookcode = cookcode;
    }

    public String getCwmvemeh() {
        return this.cwmvemeh;
    }

    public void setCwmvemeh(String cwmvemeh) {
        this.cwmvemeh = cwmvemeh;
    }

    public String getCwmvemng() {
        return this.cwmvemng;
    }

    public void setCwmvemng(String cwmvemng) {
        this.cwmvemng = cwmvemng;
    }

    public String getHsdat() {
        return this.hsdat;
    }

    public void setHsdat(String hsdat) {
        this.hsdat = hsdat;
    }

    public String getIndc() {
        return this.indc;
    }

    public void setIndc(String indc) {
        this.indc = indc;
    }

    public String getManuf() {
        return this.manuf;
    }

    public void setManuf(String manuf) {
        this.manuf = manuf;
    }

    public String getMatnr() {
        return this.matnr;
    }

    public void setMatnr(String matnr) {
        this.matnr = matnr;
    }

    public String getMblnr() {
        return this.mblnr;
    }

    public void setMblnr(String mblnr) {
        this.mblnr = mblnr;
    }

    public String getMjahr() {
        return this.mjahr;
    }

    public void setMjahr(String mjahr) {
        this.mjahr = mjahr;
    }

    public String getPrintdate() {
        return this.printdate;
    }

    public void setPrintdate(String printdate) {
        this.printdate = printdate;
    }

    public Date getProddate() {
        return this.proddate;
    }

    public void setProddate(Date proddate) {
        this.proddate = proddate;
    }



    public BigDecimal getSeq() {
        return this.seq;
    }

    public void setSeq(BigDecimal seq) {
        this.seq = seq;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getVemeh() {
        return this.vemeh;
    }

    public void setVemeh(String vemeh) {
        this.vemeh = vemeh;
    }

    public String getVemng() {
        return this.vemng;
    }

    public void setVemng(String vemng) {
        this.vemng = vemng;
    }

    public ZaeProdorder getZaeProdorder() {
        return this.zaeProdorder;
    }

    public void setZaeProdorder(ZaeProdorder zaeProdorder) {
        this.zaeProdorder = zaeProdorder;
    }

}
```

I created one servicefactory class which is as follows :
**CarandoServiceFactory,java**

```
package com;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import org.apache.olingo.odata2.processor.api.jpa.ODataJPAContext;
import org.apache.olingo.odata2.processor.api.jpa.ODataJPAServiceFactory;
import org.apache.olingo.odata2.processor.api.jpa.exception.ODataJPARuntimeException;
public class CarandoServiceFactory extends ODataJPAServiceFactory{
    private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "carandoUI5Demo";

      @Override
      public ODataJPAContext initializeODataJPAContext()
          throws ODataJPARuntimeException {

        ODataJPAContext oDatJPAContext = this.getODataJPAContext();
        try {

          EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
    oDatJPAContext.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
          oDatJPAContext.setPersistenceUnitName(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);

          return oDatJPAContext;

        } catch (Exception e) {

          throw new RuntimeException(e);

        }

      }

}
```

But now when I am running my odata service I am getting below error :

```
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<code/>
<message xml:lang="en">
"sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl: object is not an instance of declaring class. "
</message>
</error>
```

I am not able to get more detailed stack trace.
Please help me out with this issue.

The odata service 
`XXXXXcarandoUI5Demo/carando.svc/ZaeProdorders?$top=20` is giving me error.
where as `XXXXXXXXXcarandoUI5Demo/carando.svc` is working fine.

Below is metadata information

```
XXXXXXXXXcarandoUI5Demo/carando.svc/$metadata

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" Version="1.0">
<edmx:DataServices xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" m:DataServiceVersion="1.0">
<Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm" Namespace="carandoUI5Demo">
<EntityType Name="ZaeGoodsrecpt">
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="Aufnr"/>
<PropertyRef Name="ExidvC"/>
<PropertyRef Name="ExidvP"/>
<PropertyRef Name="Werks"/>
</Key>
<Property Name="Barcode" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="70"/>
<Property Name="Bfdat" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="40"/>
<Property Name="Charg" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="20"/>
<Property Name="Cookcode" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="10"/>
<Property Name="Cwmvemeh" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="3"/>
<Property Name="Cwmvemng" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="25"/>
<Property Name="Hsdat" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="10"/>
<Property Name="Aufnr" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="12"/>
<Property Name="ExidvC" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="20"/>
<Property Name="ExidvP" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="20"/>
<Property Name="Werks" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="4"/>
<Property Name="Indc" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="1"/>
<Property Name="Manuf" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="5"/>
<Property Name="Matnr" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="18"/>
<Property Name="Mblnr" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="10"/>
<Property Name="Mjahr" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="4"/>
<Property Name="Printdate" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="20"/>
<Property Name="Proddate" Type="Edm.DateTime"/>
<Property Name="Seq" Type="Edm.Decimal" Nullable="true" Precision="10"/>
<Property Name="Status" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="1"/>
<Property Name="Vemeh" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="3"/>
<Property Name="Vemng" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="17"/>
</EntityType>
<EntityType Name="ZaeProdorder">
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="Aufnr"/>
<PropertyRef Name="Werks"/>
</Key>
<Property Name="Barcode" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="50"/>
<Property Name="Batch" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="10"/>
<Property Name="Bfdat" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="40"/>
<Property Name="Cardate" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="12"/>
<Property Name="Ccook" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="4"/>
<Property Name="Compad" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="60"/>
<Property Name="Ean11" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="18"/>
<Property Name="Eddat" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="10"/>
<Property Name="Fifth" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="60"/>
<Property Name="Firstl" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="60"/>
<Property Name="Fld1" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="20"/>
<Property Name="Fld10" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="40"/>
<Property Name="Fld11" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="60"/>
<Property Name="Fld12" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="60"/>
<Property Name="Fld13" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="60"/>
<Property Name="Fld2" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="20"/>
<Property Name="Fld3" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="20"/>
<Property Name="Fld4" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="20"/>
<Property Name="Fld5" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="20"/>
<Property Name="Fld6" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="20"/>
<Property Name="Fld7" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="20"/>
<Property Name="Fld8" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="20"/>
<Property Name="Fld9" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="30"/>
<Property Name="Fourth" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="60"/>
<Property Name="Hsdate" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="12"/>
<Property Name="Aufnr" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="12"/>
<Property Name="Werks" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="4"/>
<Property Name="Jldat" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="4"/>
<Property Name="Jobno" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="5"/>
<Property Name="Lblno" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="6"/>
<Property Name="Line" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="9"/>
<Property Name="Lotno" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="10"/>
<Property Name="Maktx" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="40"/>
<Property Name="Manuf" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="5"/>
<Property Name="Matnr" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="5"/>
<Property Name="Ptype" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="1"/>
<Property Name="Qlify" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="60"/>
<Property Name="Rfgnf" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="45"/>
<Property Name="Secondl" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="60"/>
<Property Name="Serno" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="12"/>
<Property Name="Shift" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="1"/>
<Property Name="Sixth" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="60"/>
<Property Name="Slabd" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="10"/>
<Property Name="Tarag" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="10"/>
<Property Name="Teco" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="4"/>
<Property Name="Third" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="60"/>
<Property Name="Tihigh" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="40"/>
<Property Name="Title" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="60"/>
<Property Name="Tolerance" Type="Edm.Double" Nullable="true"/>
<Property Name="Weight" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="20"/>
<Property Name="Weight1" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="5"/>
<Property Name="Wgtkg" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" MaxLength="8"/>
</EntityType>
<EntityContainer Name="carandoUI5DemoContainer" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true">
<EntitySet Name="ZaeGoodsrecpts" EntityType="carandoUI5Demo.ZaeGoodsrecpt"/>
<EntitySet Name="ZaeProdorders" EntityType="carandoUI5Demo.ZaeProdorder"/>
</EntityContainer>
</Schema>
</edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```